# Executing a batch file that lives inside a jar file

Tags: java, batch-file, jar

I have a Java project that is going to be used as an executable.jar file. If my project contains a batch file within its /resources folder, how can I code my project so that I can invoke the batch file internally when the executable.jar is running?

Edit: It's a Windows 7 batch file

Comment: I don't think you can.

Comment: Would that be a windows or a linux batch file? A solution could be unpacking it, or recreating a temp file with the same content, and executing it

Comment: I don't think this is possible. However, you could quite easily write the contents of that batch script to the present working directory of your program and then execute it using `ProcessBuilder`, assuming you have write access to the present working directory.

Comment: You might extract the batch to some temporary location and execute it from there - ugly hack, IMHO. Are you sure you really need an batch file? In 9 out of 10 cases the same thing can be done in native java!

Comment: @Grove: There are no batch files on Linux - call them shell scripts :-)

Comment: i dont think its possible, but you can write a wrapper batch script which invokes your java application `jar`, then executes the batch file (based on some conditions).

Comment: @Gyro although batch/shell scripts might mean the same thing for a novice, I stand corrected, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets assume your batch file is located in the classpath at "com.mycompany.MyBatch.bat"

You first need to copy the file to `tmp`, then make it executable and then run it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final File tmp = File.createTempFile("myBatch", "batch");
    try (final ReadableByteChannel channel = Channels.newChannel(App.class.getResourceAsStream("/com/mycompany/MyBatch.bat"));
            final FileChannel fileChannel = new RandomAccessFile(tmp, "rw").getChannel()) {
        final ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
        while (channel.read(bb) > 0) {
            bb.flip();
            fileChannel.write(bb);
            bb.clear();
        }
    }
    tmp.setExecutable(true);
    //run script
}
```

Comment: so if I am using Runtime.getRuntime().exec("what is the command that goes here?");

Comment: Step one don't use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec`, use a [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html). Step 2 `ProcessBuilder pb =
   new ProcessBuilder(tmp.getAbsolutePath(), "myArg1", "myArg2");`

Comment: It works! Well, I cannot get it to work with ProcessBuilder, and the second argument to File.createTempFile() needs to be ".bat", but thanks very much for the help! One thing I can't wrap my head around, whats the bb.flip() for?

Comment: A `ByteBuffer` is essentially a `Byte[]` with a marker and a size. When you write it writes from where the marker is until the buffer is full or the channel is exhausted. When you read you read from where the marker is until size. When you call `flip` you are saying that you are done writing so you set the size to the current position of the marker and you reset the marker. You may want to read [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) for a more thorough description.